# how can i read cookie value that written by jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

i created a cookie by jquery version: jquery-1.10.2 by this syntax

```
$.cookie('coockiename', 'abc');
```

on my client after that user click a link and redirect to an action but in this action i can not read that cookie in my request by this syntax

```
Request.Cookies["coockiename"]
```

and it's null and unavailable.

i think created cookie is not written in my request is it true or not and how can i handle it?
(my sample application developed in mvc3 razor)

Comment: Are you using jquery.cookie plugin for this? jQuery itself does not support `$.cookie()` function. If you do use the plugin, make sure the cookie is actually set before redirect (use `return false` onclick and e.g. try to log the value with `console.log()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to set the path of the cookie to the root of the site to ensure it can be read in C#:

```
$.cookie('coockiename', 'abc', { path : '/' });
```